# Export like in texture view?

Tags: texturing, materials, unity

i've made a model with texture (via UV map: mark steam unwrap..) and it's looking great but when i export it (to put it in unity), the model looks like when it's in material view. how can i do to make it looks like in texture view ? Thank you a lot.

Comment: if you could provide some images to understand better it would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the material isn't exported (except its name and mesh assignment basically). Anyway, as long as you change the rendering engine you have to change the material, interoperability is rare in this context.

Once in Unity, the material might be here among your assets, with the same name as in Blender, but with blank default parameters. You will have to set its settings properly and assign its maps (which might also need to be imported first).